# Improving performance of Excel startup by avoiding Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, .net, interop, vsto, activator

In our .Net application, Excel is getting run. Is there any way to avoid calling `Activator.CreateInstance()` when starting an Excel instance? `new Excel.Application()` causes it to be called.

This is the code which opens excel :

```
        public void OpenExcel(string filePath, Action beforeCloseAction, Action beforeSaveAction = null)
    {
        _excelApp = new Application
        {
            DisplayAlerts = false,
            WindowState = XlWindowState.xlMaximized,
            Visible = false,
        };

        _onBeforeSaveCall = beforeSaveAction;
        _excelApp.WorkbookBeforeSave += WorkbookBeforeSave;

        _onBeforeCloseCall = beforeCloseAction;
        _excelApp.WorkbookBeforeClose += WorkbookBeforeClose;

        _excelWorkbooks = _excelApp.Workbooks;

        SetExcelWorkbook(_excelWorkbooks.Open(filePath));

        _excelWorkbook.Saved = true;
    }
```

[image: dotTrace profiling output:]

Comment: I don't think calling `Activator.CreateInstance()` is why it takes so long. Opening Excel is most likely the problem.

Comment: This is irrelevant, you are starting a new process.  An expensive operation in Windows, Excel is also a rather giant chunk of code.  Trying to shave nanoseconds from the managed call makes no sense.

Comment: Hans, I am not shaving nanoseconds!!! Just thinking that 12 seconds for Activator.CreateInstance() is a lot of time!

Comment: Yes, that's about what it takes to get Excel.exe up and running.  Your profiler isn't smart enough to see that this time was spent waiting for another process to start and respond to the COM call.  You can't make Excel start faster unless you invest in hardware.

Comment: @FarshidZaker: so you think that if you could just avoid that call, Excel could be started for free? The reason it takes so long is because it has to start Excel. Try launch Excel manually, and see how long that takes.

Comment: Try removing any add-ins from Excel and then starting it then. The above answers are correct, but a common reason for long start up times in Excel is due to add-ins loading. 12 seconds doesn't seem that bad though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you run a profiler so that you know where the performance issues lie? I'd be very surprised if the call to Activator.CreateInstance was a performance bottleneck in your application. Presumably you will not be creating many Excel instances per second, but rather one instance on start up. Whether this is done by Activator.CreateInstance or not should make little difference.

Comment: The above code gets 15193 ms, while 12718 ms of it is occupied by Activator.CreateInstance()

Comment: @FarshidZaker yes, but that doesn't mean `Activator` is to blame... simply **loading Excel takes a while!**

Comment: @FarshidZaker: Sure, but the vast majority of that time will be used within the construction of the object. The fact that this is being invoked via Activator.CreateInstance() won't be adding a significant amount of time to this. As Hans Passant says, this is likely to be a tiny fraction of a second.

Comment: Please take a look at attached dotTrace snapshot. Please let me know if I am wrong about CreateInstance()

Comment: The profiler can only tell you what it knows about. Activator creates an instance of the type, but the type itself is implemented in unmanaged code. In the case of Excel.Application, a process is started and this simply takes time. Try starting Excel manually, you will see that this takes time. Creating an Excel.Application instance generally takes a significant fraction of the time it takes to start an interactive Excel session. Unfortunately there is no way around this.